# Installing a package within Spyder IDE

Tags: python, installation, package, spyder

I have a script in Spyder named `test_script.py` that looks as such:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
# import csv
from datetime import datetime
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch, ClientError
```

But whenever I run it, I get the following answer:

```
runfile('/Users/first.last/test_script.py', wdir='/Users/first.last')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/Users/first.last/test_script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch, ClientError

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instagram_private_api'
```

Okay, fair enough. But then I try to install it within Spyder's terminal based off the [instructions found here](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api) but I get met with the following error:

```
First-MacBook-Pro:~ first.last$ pip install git+https://git@github.com/ping/instagram_private_api.git@1.6.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

So it tells me that `pip` does not exist. So then I run the following:

```
first-MacBook-Pro:~ first.last$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2617k  100 2617k    0     0  5464k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5476k
first-MacBook-Pro:~ first.last$ python3 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-63.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-22.1.2 setuptools-63.1.0 wheel-0.37.1
```

Okay great, so I assume we're good to go but then when I run the same code as above to install the instagram_private_api module, I still get the same error:

First-MacBook-Pro:~ first.last$ pip install git+https://git@github.com/ping/instagram_private_api.git@1.6.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip", line 5, in 
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Here is screenshot of everything together for reference:

[image]

Comment: That spyder IDE from anaconda? If so try installing same library from `Anaconda prompt`  & let me know

Comment: I have no idea if it's from anaconda. Nonetheless, where should I run that? Because when I run it in the Terminal I just get `bash: Anaconda: command not found`

Comment: search ` anaconda prompt` in mac...It is built in package with `anaconda` ...or else you can find in UI too it is named as `CMD exe prompt` https://dev.to/dendihandian/creating-new-environment-in-anaconda-4b99

Comment: Able to find it?

Comment: No I did not find it

Comment: Also I should note that I'm on a Mac and the link you provided was for Windows

Comment: Seems like you are using the Spyder standalone version for MacOS. To be able to use packages outside the ones blundled with the installer you can check the Spyder wiki (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder)